# Biometric authentication with back-end verification service process

Tags: authentication, mobile

I am working on an application where I will be using [Android](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=android%20biometric%20authentication%202020&t=brave&df=y&ia=web) and [iOS](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ios%20biometric%20authentication&t=brave&df=y&ia=web) biometric authentication.

Coding the use of biometrics on the devices, including prompting and determining whether or not the user device supports it is easy. I can get fingerprint authentication up, face recognition, etc. without any issues. On Android I can easily use the [CryptoObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/biometrics/BiometricPrompt.CryptoObject) to store data locally and it seems just as easy on iOS.

I am wondering what the best practices are for verifying this authentication with the back-end as well.

If I understand things correctly, the happy path process should simply be:

1. Prompt user
2. User authenticates with thumbprint, face, etc.
3. Callback is made on authentication success
4. Extract encrypted data on the device
5. Restore session with the back-end services

My problem is with steps #4 and #5.

**What is recommended to actually be stored?**

I am hesitant to store sensitive data, even if encrypted, on the user's physical device. It seems obvious not to store the username/password combination, but what are people actually using to restore the session?

- Long-lived Session ID?
- License key or bearer token-like identifier for the user?
- Should I be adding a new endpoint that uploads custom data from the results that I may have missed in documentation?

Right now, after the user authenticates, I am storing the Device ID along-side a generated Token (stored with one-way encryption on the server-side). It feels non-secure to store this data on the local device, unless that is the way to do it.

Comment: Roughly, yes. Store a certificate of sorts encrypted by the biometric device. Present that certificate to your backend to prove identity. If the user hasn't logged in within X days, challenge them with a sms phrase, or a password request to prove they are X.

Comment: On iOS more precise: Create a certificate. Encrypt it using the Secure Enclave. Store the encrypted certificate in the keychain. Be prepared for the certificate to be lost (if the user turns biometrics off for example, or if the user migrated to a different device) and be able to handle this somehow. Biometrics must never be the only way to access, but just a convenience).

Comment: You might be interested to explore [WebAuthn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebAuthn) standard, there might be example reference implementations already that deal with Biometrics and how to set up keys for exchange with an API.

Comment: Thanks all - it seems like I'm on the right track already. I definitely need a new endpoint for this it seems like.